# App crash when phone contact synced with facebook friends contact in ios

Tags: ios7

when i am syncing facebook contact in my iphone contact then my app crash in getting all phone contact. App crashed everytime on first name giving bad access. and app work fine if facebook friends is not synced .Here is my code:

```
+(NSMutableArray *)getAllContacts
{
    CFErrorRef *error = nil;

    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);

    __block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
    if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) { // we're on iOS 6
        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            accessGranted = granted;
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        });
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    }
    else { // we're on iOS 5 or older
        accessGranted = YES;
    }

    if (accessGranted)
    {

#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"Fetching contact info ----> ");
#endif
        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
        ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
        CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName);
        CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
        NSMutableArray* items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:nPeople];

        for (int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *contacts = [NSMutableDictionary new];
            ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);

            //get First Name and Last Name

            NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

            NSString *lastName =  (__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

            NSString *name=@"";

            if ([firstName length]>0 && [lastName length]>0)
                name= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];
            else if ([firstName length]>0 && [lastName length]==0)
                name= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName];
            else if ([firstName length]==0 && [lastName length]>0)
                name= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lastName];
            else
                name= @"No Name";

            contacts[@"name"]=name;

            // get contacts picture, if pic doesn't exists, show standart one

            NSData  *imgData = (__bridge NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
            UIImage *image= [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
            if (!image)
                image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profilebase_small.png"];
            contacts[@"image"]=image;
            //get Phone Numbers

            NSMutableArray *phoneNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            ABMultiValueRef multiPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
            for(CFIndex i=0;i<ABMultiValueGetCount(multiPhones);i++) {

                CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiPhones, i);
                NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge NSString *) phoneNumberRef;
                [phoneNumbers addObject:phoneNumber];
            }

            contacts[@"numbers"]=phoneNumbers;
            //get Contact email

            NSMutableArray *contactEmails = [NSMutableArray new];
            ABMultiValueRef multiEmails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);

            for (CFIndex i=0; i<ABMultiValueGetCount(multiEmails); i++) {
                CFStringRef contactEmailRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiEmails, i);
                NSString *contactEmail = (__bridge NSString *)contactEmailRef;

                [contactEmails addObject:contactEmail];
                // NSLog(@"All emails are:%@", contactEmails);

            }

            contacts[@"emails"]=contactEmails;



            [items addObject:contacts];
        }
        return items;
    } else
    {
#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"Cannot fetch Contacts :( ");
#endif
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have u find the answer for this question ? I am also facing the same problem . If you have solved the problem then please tell the solution.

Comment: Replace this line CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
        with CFIndex nPeople = CFArrayGetCount(allPeople);

Comment: You should write it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook); with CFIndex nPeople = CFArrayGetCount(allPeople);